# jQueryのeqは何の略でしょうか？

Tags: javascript, jquery

いろんなウェブサイトで検索したのですが、一体これは何の略なのでしょうか？

Comment: 指定したインデックスに等しい（**eq**ual)要素ってことだと思います。

Comment: [eq.](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/eq.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eq`はequals(equals to)だと思われます。これは等価比較の識別子としては一般的なもので、`:lt()`=less thanや`:gt()`=greater thanといった他のセレクターとも統一性があります。